# Wrong error message when attempting to use diamond in username

Tags: bug, display-names

I was testing out [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188555/fake-moderator-using-a-moderator-icon#comment580873_188556) (and a few other symbols), and I got the following error message:

> Display Name can only contain letters, digits, spaces, apostrophes or hyphens and must start with a letter or digit

Isn't this false? We allow Unicode in usernames. I get the same error while trying to add `@` to my username (and most probably any other blacklisted character).

It should probably be:

> Display names cannot contain the character(s):

and list all of the characters used in the username that are blacklisted.

Comment: Isn't it a whitelist based on Unicode [categories](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/), such as maybe just letters? (What looks like funny symbols to us, might in fact just be letters in some scripts? But indeed, for some weird reason, things like mathematical symbols are in the letter categories as well.)

Comment: @Arjan Yeah, but that doesn't explain why ᛜ is allowed.

Comment: Unfortunately the unicode panda doesn't work. I am disappoint.

Comment: @Manishearth, maybe that's because the panda lives outside of the basic multilingual plane.

Comment:        , but I never tried in user names...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That makes me a sad panda.

Comment: @Arjan Give me a few, I can try them out. Either way, an empty diamond shouldn't be in the multilingual plane.

Comment: And I'm sure people have tried Zalgo in display names too ;-)