# Consequence for adding ♦

Tags: support, moderators, display-names

As many of you know, the ***♦*** tag is for moderator use only (e.g. Moderator name ♦). However, suppose a user adds this to the end of their name. Is there a set consequence for this? Will they lose their reputation, or will their account be banned?

I do not want to add this diamond, I'm just wondering what would happen if I did.

Comment: I assume it's not allowed, but I haven't tried. Why don't you try it "for science!"? :)

Comment: @Shokhet It's not worth the risk if my account gets banned. :\

Comment: If you made it clear that it was just an experiment, and asked a mod (either by custom flag or contact form) to change the name back right after, you should be fine. I don't think they'd be so harsh if it's clear that it wasn't done maliciously. (Besides, I'm pretty sure you wouldn't be able to use that character in a name)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234897/215590 suggests that you will not be able to add it, even if you try.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188555/fake-moderator-using-a-moderator-icon#comment580873_188556 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188570/wrong-error-message-when-attempting-to-use-diamond-in-username . As for consequences - it depends, but its *impolite* and *very much frowned upon* to pretend to be someone else. Oh and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99914/what-are-the-rules-governing-display-names-and-avatars . So simply, you can't , shouldn't and wouldn't (would you?)

Comment: Thanks guys :) I didn't know this question was already answered.