# Image on my profile always gets truncated

Tags: support, profile-picture

The image on my profile always gets truncated. I tried different images and different sizes, but they all get truncated.

I could not find any image size information in the Stack Overflow help file.

Comment: Make the image taller than wider. Or have a 1 : 1 aspect ratio.

Comment: ??
 Can you please be more specific? do we have any guidelines on this?

Comment: Made it bigger still truncated.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't look to me like it's being *truncated*. Rather, it looks like it's getting *compressed* (or *squished*, if you prefer).

Truncated would mean that some portion of it was getting cut off…like this:

[image]

Instead, it's being automatically compressed to fit into the space available for profile pictures:

[image]

You can generate the same effect yourself in any image editing program by reducing the horizontal dimension without reducing the vertical dimension. In Microsoft Paint, click "Resize", uncheck "Maintain aspect ratio", and make the horizontal size smaller.

This is a hint—the aspect ratio of your original image does not match that used for profile pics. In other words, it's a rectangle, but profile pictures are squares.

The size of the large image displayed on your profile page is something like 128x128 pixels, but the actual size of the original image is not particularly important. The image is resized automatically in different parts of the UI, depending on the space available and the focus of the content. If you upload a square image, it will look right.

And like others have suggested, now is a good time to consider changing your profile picture to something a bit more appropriate. Look for images that are approximately square. Like this one:

[image]

Comment: I plan to keep my image. You can't both agree and disagree with something. If you disagree with my picture then logically you should give me an upvote at 
[Fake moderator using a Moderator icon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188555/fake-moderator-using-a-moderator-icon)

Comment: @Joe So you've set your profile pic just to troll for upvotes on a question that has already been marked as a duplicate? Lame. Anyway, one certainly can simultaneously think you should change your profile pic *and* disagree that we should create a policy that explicitly bans this. We can't have policies for everything. Some things just have to be based on common sense. There's no policy that says people who attempt to hack into the site will be banned, but you can bet on it happening when you try.

Comment: .I just wanted to prove how voting in Meta is dysfunctional and I firmly believe anyone who read this post honestly will agree with me.

Comment: @Joe Which part is dysfunctional? The fact that rants from abrasive users who just want to cause trouble get heavily downvoted? No, I think that's working as designed.