# ꕺ (U+A57A Vai Syllable Kpoo) is allowed in character names as the last character

Tags: feature-request, display-names, unicode

I believe this should be changed so ꕺ can not be the last character of a name at minimum.
This could be a bug in my opinion because it provides confusion with diamond mods.  Although other symbols are blocked from what I understand but this does technically look different.

I have changed my name to such to demonstrate the confusion at least temporarily.

They say imitation is the greatest form of flattery so maybe this should be accepted because to anyone who is familiar with SO I doubt this would cause an issue.

[image]

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about; [it doesn't render for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCL5U.png). Can you provide screenshots of the problem.

Comment: @Laurel https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibCGo.png What OS and browser are you on?

Comment: Considering [this question's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230643/is-making-yourself-appear-at-first-glance-to-be-a-moderator-acceptable-behavio), no, it's nto allowed.

Comment: That being said, the hollow diamond is not the correct one...

Comment: @Catija All other characters that resemble diamonds are blocked so yes I'm not sure.

Comment: Hollow diamond renders for me. Also, unicode abuse is sad, and its probably impossible to block all *diamond like characters* from usernames without *blocking unicode*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unicode is vast and growing. And while the [actual diamond character we use is blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230654/135565) I suspect a regex to block anything that remotely looks like a mod diamond would be long and growing. I also have no idea if we have any users who speak [the vai language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vai_language), and might choose to use that for their username,

If someone is pretending to be a moderator, or there's some confusion over a user with a diamond like symbol, let a mod or CM know and we'll deal with it

Comment: Still I don't see any problem with a case-by-case addition of invalid last characters as they pop up. Not necessary to get them all in one shot, we can just get them as we see them used, and in this case it's not prohibitively "long and growing"; even if every few months or years one or two discovered diamond-like characters is added it's still not that crazy. If any user ever needs that character, finds that it's not allowed, then cares enough to make a meta post about it then it can be revisited, but my gut tells me there's no reason to preemptively care about that case now.

Comment: That said, there currently appear to be no users on any sites with that character (ꕺ) in their display name, at least as of the last sede update.