# Block diamond symbols in usernames ᛜ

Tags: feature-request

I’m not sure if the moderator diamond is blocked from being included in a username, I assume it is.

However I recently come across a user who was using this symbol in their username: ᛜ

As a fairly new user I assumed this signified something until I realised it was simply what they had entered.

Would it be a good idea to prevent users from having this symbol in their username to prevent misuse or confusion?

Comment: Diamonds are blocked from usernames

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I assume you mean the moderator diamond specifically (since apparently other kinds of diamond symbols are not blocked from usernames)?

Comment: I vaguely remember an old meta post about this. I'll dig.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296347/155739

Comment: Forgot about that one actually